# Simple C++ program help compiling

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

Guys I am a starting programmer and need help. I am working on PART A ONLY of an assignment located here: http://cs.binghamton.edu/~sgreene/cs240-2010f/labs/lab2.html

However I am having trouble compiling my programs. Please tell me what im doing wrong in my makefile and in the cpp files! Here are my files:

```
# CS240 Lab2 Makefile 

all: lab2

lab2: lab2.o
    g++ -Wall lab2.o -o lab2

lab2.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp -o lab2.o

lab2.o: tenstrings.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c tenstrings.cpp -o lab2.o
```

---

```
/*tenstrings.h*/
#ifndef TENSTRNGS
#define TENSTRNGS

class TenStrings
{
public: 
    // Default Constructor
    TenStrings();
}
#endif
```

---

```
/* tenstrings.cpp */

#include "TenStrings.h"

//Default Constructor
TenStrings::TenStrings()
{}
```

---

```
/* main.cpp */

#include "TenStrings.h"

int main()
{
    TenStrings varTen;
    return 0; 
}
```

---

As you can see this isnt even a program, its just to get me started in compiling but i am getting bunch of errors:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________
Makefile:12: warning: overriding commands for target 'lab2.o'
Makefile:9: warning: ignoring old commands for target 'lab2.o'
g++ -Wall -c tenstrings.cpp -o lab2.o
In file included from tenstrings.cpp:6:
TenStrings.h:11:3: warning: no newline at end of file
tenstrings.cpp:7: error: new types may not be defined in a return type
tenstrings.cpp:7: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
_________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make code show in a fixed-width font, indent it 4 spaces! It will look much better!

Comment: http://cplusplus.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=New_types_may_not_be_defined_in_a_return_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your makefile should look more like this:

```
all: lab2

lab2: main.o tenstrings.o
    g++ main.o tenstrings.o -o lab2

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp -o main.o

tenstrings.o: tenstrings.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c tenstrings.cpp -o tenstrings.o
```

that might sort out your first two errors.

Comment: Nearly there - get rid of lab2.o

Comment: Thanks. It finally compiles but I still get a message: TenStrings.h: warning: no newline at end of file .. I know this is just a warning but should I be worried about anything here?

Comment: Yeah, literally add a new line to the end of the file. You'll probably find that there is nothing at all after the semi-colon. Just go there and hit enter.

Comment: k thanks. on that link I gave in my orignal post on the lab assignment, What does Part B of the lab mean? Do I have to create an array of empty strings in my tenstrings.cpp file? Or do I have to say CONST string1 = "", CONST string2 = "", etc.. I'm confused about the [] though. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure which part of it you don't understand. So, briefly - You'll want an array of strings (either pointers that you allocate memory for, or fixed length, making it a 2D array) as a private member in your TenStrings class. That's what the square brackets are for, e.g. [10]. So your first string would be string[0], and the tenth would be string[9]. Then something like strcpy (string[0], "First string"); (or its equivalent if you use a string class) etc, in the constructor.

Comment: should this go in the header file or in tenstrings.cpp?

Comment: also why do you do strcpy? Cant I just do assignment such as: string myStrings[] = {"First String", "Second String", .....};   or am i not understanding the lab correctly?

Comment: The declaration of the strings should go in the private: section of the TenStrings class in the header file. The definition of the constructor, which will be setting up the "First string" etc., should go in the cpp file. (Although it is possible to do it in the .h)

Comment: Sadly, it is not possible to initialise array members in C++. Yes, it is possible to initialise _global_ arrays like that, but not class members.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a noob. but You said that the declaration of the strings should go in the private section in the header file, but my class TenStrings in header is public

Comment: No problem, just add a section in there starting with private: in exactly the same way as it says public:. It will still work fine if it's in the public: section, but best practice is to put it in private. That way, code outside the TenStrings class will not be allowed to mess with the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon at the end of the class declaration. Also, you can rewrite your Makefile a bit more simply; you don't need a target for each file:

```
all: lab2

lab2: lab2.o
    g++ -Wall lab2.o -o lab2

lab2.o: main.cpp tenstrings.cpp
    g++ -Wall -o lab2.o tenstrings.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: If you're going to process all the source files in one go (fine for a small case like this, silly for a dozen, and foolishness for hundreds) there is little point in building an object file and then an executable: you can just make the executable. But do it properly (each source file gives a object file, then link the .o's) just for the drill.

Comment: Thanks. It finally compiles but I still get a message:  TenStrings.h: warning: no newline at end of file  ..  I know this is just a warning but should I be worried about anything here?

Comment: btw..this makefile doesnt work that you gave me..but the semicolon did help

Answer (score 1):

You don't terminate the TenStrings class with a ';' at the end in TenStrings.h, which is what the error is.

Comment: Thanks. It finally compiles but I still get a message: TenStrings.h: warning: no newline at end of file .. I know this is just a warning but should I be worried about anything here?

Comment: Yeah, literally add a new line to the end of the file. You'll probably find that there is nothing at all after the semi-colon. Just go there and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a semicolon at the end of your class definition.

```
/*tenstrings.h*/
#ifndef TENSTRNGS
#define TENSTRNGS

class TenStrings
{
public: 
    // Default Constructor
    TenStrings();
}; // <--- !!!!
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same `make` target defined twice. Then you don't link all parts of the project. This should be something like:

```
all: lab2

lab2: lab.o lab2.o
    g++ -Wall lab.o lab2.o -o lab2

lab.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp -o lab.o

lab2.o: tenstrings.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c tenstrings.cpp -o lab2.o
```